# '1234 tell me that you love me more', the 4th digit does not display in serial

Tags: python, c++, serialization, raspberry-pi, attiny

An ATTiny85 send a 3 digits integer 123 to an ATTiny45 using serial communication which then send that to a Raspberry pi using serial communication.
It is working!

BUT

If I send 1234, which mean one more digit, it does not work anymore. I changed the baud rate and the speed of reading, I changed the code in many way but I cannot read 4 digits at the end of this chain. It does not work and quickly display random characters.

code for the ATTiny85:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SendOnlySoftwareSerial.h>

#define TX 4

int c1 = 123;


SendOnlySoftwareSerial toA45(TX);

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Wire.begin();
  toA45.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  
  toA45.println(c1); 
  delay(5000);
}
```

code for the ATTiny45

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SendOnlySoftwareSerial.h>
//#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <ReceiveOnlySoftwareSerial.h>

#define RX 3
#define TX 4

//SoftwareSerial toRip(RX,TX);
SendOnlySoftwareSerial toRip(TX);
ReceiveOnlySoftwareSerial fromA85(RX);


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  
  Wire.begin();
  toRip.begin(9600); // changing rate does not help
  fromA85.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if (fromA85.available()){
      toRip.println(fromA85.read());
  }
}
```

Code for the Raspberry pi0

```
import serial
ser=serial.Serial('dev/serial0',9600,parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ON
              bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,timeout=1)
while True:
    data = ser.readline()
    print(data)
```

[EDIT: Pictures with 3 and 4 digits which are from the ASCII table. It takes 1 to 5 readings and this is what is displayed. ]
[image: 3 digits]

[image: 4 digits]

Comment: This code requires C++. Editing tags.

Comment: Try to connect the ATTiny85 directly to the Pi (if electrically possible) or remove the ATTiny85 temporarily and run its code in the ATTiny45 to see what happens.

Comment: The Raspberry Pi and ATTiny45 or ATTiny85 works like a charm together, even with longer integer. But as soon as I make one an intermediary it does not like the 4th digit.

Answer (score 0):

I got other issues continuing to develop on the same breadboard. The breadboard was old. I got a brand new one.
I can send 4 digits with no issue 99% of the time.
I wonder if there is an easy way to test a breadboard and to determine when this is the end.